# Two simple python errors - Upgrading python 2 to 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

all! I wrote a script to write an algorithm to test if a file is malicious or not. Now I have a separate file which I run from CMD to actually apply the algorithm to the test file. However, I am getting two errors which I am sure are because the lines have been written for python 2.x. The errors are:

```
 File "main.py", line 203, in <module>
    data = extract_infos(args.FILE)
  File "main.py", line 111, in extract_infos
    res['SectionsMeanEntropy'] = sum(entropy)/float(len(entropy))
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `entropy = list(entropy)` and then continue as usual.

Comment: `map()` returns an iterator in Python 3, so you must enclose it with `list()` or `tuple()`